# How to use this phrase - contribution to solving a problem

Tags: word-usage, grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I am wondering whether this sentence is correct:

> He earned award X for his contribution to solving problem Y.

Can someone please advise whether "contribution to solving problem Y" in the above sentence is correct? Normally, to is followed by verb, right?

Comment: “To” is used as the first part of the full infinitive form of a verb, but it’s also a preposition (and occasionally an adverb) that has many other uses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a perfectly fine sentence.